# I am learning RECT and at the moment of using a component it is placed under the first component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-router

As it says in the title I am learning so I want to do this

```
import Navbar from "../components/navbar";
import Footer from "../components/footer";
import Contactanos from "../components/contactanos";

export default function ContactanosPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Contactanos />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

and when I go to the path in this case is localhost:300/contacts the components are superimposed one on top of the other except for the footer which goes under everything.

Here I send the code of the components

```
import '../css/footer.css'
export default function Footer() {
    return (
        <div className="pie-pagina">
            <div className="grupo-2">
                <small>&copy; 2023 <b>Los Mixturiados</b> - Todos los Derechos Reservados.</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import '../css/navbar.css'

export default function Navbar() {

    return (
        <>
            <div className="contenedor-header">
                <header>
                    <div className="logo">
                        <a href="/">Los Mixturiados</a>

                    </div>
                    <nav className="nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li><Link to={'/'}>INICIO</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to={'/menus'}>MENUS</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to={'/contacto'}>CONTACTAME</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <div className="nav-responsive">
                        <i className="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
                    </div>
                </header>

            </div></>
    )
}

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './routes/Home';
import Menus from './components/Menus';
import ContactanosPage from './routes/ContactanosComp';


const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Home />,
    errorElement: <h1>Ocurrio un Error</h1>
  },
  {
    path: '/menus',
    element: <Menus />,
  },
  {
    path: '/contacto',
    element: <ContactanosPage/>,
  }
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

I was trying to do everything to create another div, do it with the insibile div <></> I have tried everything but I can't get it to fit well what could I improve or what could I change?

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear what any issue is with the code or from what you are describing. Can you [edit] to clarify what any specific issue or problem is and what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: What happens is that I have components and when I want to direct you to localhost:3000 I am using 3 components that would be Navbar, Contact Us, Footer then all are put first at the top of the page if I comment for example Navbar now appears Footer and is not well ordered.  @DrewReese

Comment: In a few words, when I redirect to this location http://localhost:3000/menus I only get the Navbar and the other components are in the back. @DrewReese

Comment: For example, I want the NavBar to appear at the top, then the contact component at the bottom and the footer at the end, but everything appears at the top.  @DrewReese

Comment: What happens is that all the components overlap each other and that's exactly why I had created a separate component to make it a little easier, but when I go to localhost:3000/menus the components are rendered one on top of the other.

Comment: It is the first code

Comment: Yes, the error is not because the components are not rendered, the error is because the components are rendered on top of each other, they are all at the top of the page.

Comment: You could say that what I want then is for them to come out separately, for example
**Example**
- NavBar
- Some Code
- Footer

I want them to appear separately and in the order I enter the component, I do not want one to appear on top of the other.

Comment: Ok, I can understand the Navbar - some code - Footer part. What exactly do you want to appear separately? And can you clarify what exactly you mean by "appear on top of the other"? As in, is there some visual overlap where something is rendered on top of another component, or do you simply mean it's rendered under/below other content on the page vertically?

Comment: Yes, when I use export default function Contact UsPage() it would return the navbar - (here I could add some code) - footer all 3 in their respective orders as a normal page.
[Here you can see the example](https://i.imgur.com/UfgSzg9.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting the `Navbar` and `Footer` to be rendered ***unconditionally*** on the page, and all the routed content, e.g `Home`, `Menus`, and `Contactos`, be ***conditionally*** rendered between them, e.g. on routes, then the suggestion would be to create a [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#layout-routes) for the main UI. The layout route would render `Navbar`, an `Outlet` for nested route content, and the `Footer` components.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from "../components/navbar";
import Footer from "../components/footer";

const AppLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Outlet />
    <Footer />
  </>
);

export default AppLayout;
```

Import `AppLayout` and integrate into the routes configuration.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppLayout from '../components/AppLayout';
import Home from './routes/Home';
import Menus from './components/Menus';
import Contactanos from '../components/contactanos';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <AppLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <Home />,
        errorElement: <h1>Ocurrio un Error</h1>
      },
      {
        path: '/menus',
        element: <Menus />,
      },
      {
        path: '/contacto',
        element: <Contactanos />,
      }
    ]
  },
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```